# pybind11 (embedded) import into root namespace

Tags: c++, python-3.x, pybind11

I want to ask pybind11 to import all the symbols from a given module into the root namespace, so that I can access them without having to qualify them by module name.

The pure python equivalent would be, instead of the commented code:

```
# import my_module
# my_module.foo() # needs a qualifying scope

from my_module import *
foo()
```

Now in pybind11 it's easy to achieve the commented code with

```
py::module my_module = py::module::import("my_module");
```

The way I've found of achieving the the same thing in pybind11 is by explicitly exec'ing the python code

```
py::exec("from my_module import *");
```

which is less hassle than e.g. looping over all the symbols in `my_module` and manually adding to `globals()` (if that even works, I didn't try it). But it seems a little hacky to me, is there a better way?